# Limit problem with fifth root

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt[5]{1+5x}-1-x}$$

How to solve this limit without L'Hopital rule and Taylor series?

Comment: Note that $$\forall a,b,\in \mathbb R\left(a^5-b^5=(a-b)\left(a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+a^3+b^4\right)\right)$$ and set $a=\root5\of{1+5x}$ and $b=1+x$.I didn't see it through, but it should work.

Answer (score 6):

We have
$$\dfrac1{a-b} = \dfrac{a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4}{a^5-b^5}$$
Taking $a=\sqrt[5]{1+5x}$ and $b=1+x$, we obtain that
\begin{align}
\dfrac1{\sqrt[5]{1+5x}-1-x} = \dfrac{(1+5x)^{4/5} + (1+5x)^{3/5}(1+x) + (1+5x)^{2/5}(1+x)^{2} + (1+5x)^{1/5}(1+x)^3 + (1+x)^4}{(1+5x)-(1+x)^5}
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt[5]{1+5x}-1-x} & = \dfrac{(1+5x)^{4/5} + (1+5x)^{3/5}(1+x) + (1+5x)^{2/5}(1+x)^{2} + (1+5x)^{1/5}(1+x)^3 + (1+x)^4}{-10-15x-5x^2-x^3}
\end{align}
Now taking the limit as $x \to 0$, we obtain the limit to be
$$L = \dfrac{1+1+1+1+1}{-10} = -\dfrac12$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the simple substitution $1 + 5x = t^{5}$ so that $x = (t^{5} - 1)/5$. Then as $x \to 0$ we have $t \to 1$. Therefore
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt[5]{1 + 5x} - 1 - x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 1}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{t^{5} - 1}{5}\right)^{2}}{t - 1 - \dfrac{t^{5} - 1}{5}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{5}\lim_{t \to 1}\frac{(t^{5} - 1)^{2}}{5(t - 1) - (t^{5} - 1)}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{5}\lim_{t \to 1}\frac{(t - 1)^{2}}{5(t - 1) - (t^{5} - 1)}\cdot\left(\frac{t^{5} - 1}{t - 1}\right)^{2}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{5}\lim_{t \to 1}\frac{t - 1}{5 - (t^{4} + t^{3} + t^{2} + t + 1)}\cdot\left(5\right)^{2}\notag\\
&= -5\lim_{t \to 1}\frac{t - 1}{(t^{4} + t^{3} + t^{2} + t) - 4}\notag\\
&= -5\lim_{t \to 1}\frac{t - 1}{(t^{4} - 1) + (t^{3} - 1) + (t^{2} - 1) + (t - 1)}\notag\\
&= -5\lim_{t \to 1}\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{t^{4} - 1}{t - 1} + \dfrac{t^{3} - 1}{t - 1} + \dfrac{t^{2} - 1}{t - 1} + 1}\notag\\
&= -5\cdot\frac{1}{4 + 3 + 2 + 1}\notag\\
&= -\frac{5}{10} = -\frac{1}{2}\notag
\end{align}